# My Android app is not able to post an image on another my Facebook profile. setting or code?

Tags: android, facebook, multiple-accounts

I'm trying to make an application for Android that can post a picture on the Facebook Wall. I did, but I cannot post something on the wall of another Facebook profile of mine, in other words my application asks me to login to Facebook, if I login with the account with which I have registered my app then my app post the image on the wall of this account, but if I login with another account my app fails to post anything on this wall.

I think it's a problem of setting and not code (because in first case it's work). On the developer page in "status and review" to the question "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" I replay "YES". But this does not seem to be enough. What do I do?

Facebook SDK version 3.18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are on sandbox mode, when you release your app, it'll be available. Meanwhile, you can't, just with your account.